# Having an unordered list to be in a single line

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having issues with styling my unordered list. What I'm trying to achieve is to have an ordered list to be next to each other like a star rating system, however, the last `<li></li>` unordered list is lower than the rest. I have tried `position: relative` and `display: left` but no progress. I'm using angular 13 to display the stars as an unordered list. Suggestions?

### Component

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    rating: number;
    stars: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    selectedValue: number;  

    onRatingsChanged(value) {
        this.selectedValue = value;
    }
```

### HTML

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars">
        <li (click)="onRatingsChanged(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i></li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
            div {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }

            .rating-list li {
                float: left;
                color: #ddd;
                display: flex;
                /* transition: 0.5s;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center; */
                padding: 10px 5px;
            }

            .rating-list li:hover,
            .rating-list li:hover ~ li, .rating-list li.selected {
                color: #ffd700 !important;
            }

            .rating-list {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style: none;
                position: relative;
            }

            ul {
                margin-left: 1em;
                margin-top: 1em
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add a fiddle or code snippet? It would be easy to track the issue.

Comment: I'd advise to learn some CSS layout basics. Tbh, your current CSS looks like wild guessing. `display: flex` would make sense on the `ul`, but not on the `li`. Along with `display: flex` on the parent you should not be using `float: left` on the list items.

Comment: MDN is usually a very reliable source for looking up CSS. For example, you would soon find that display: left doesn't exist on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and float: left is intended for a different purpose (floating elements so adjacent elemsnt sit alongside and then under them). I wouldn't recommend just guessing at what properties can do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the styling and try this first. If it's what you need, add the rest, colors, font size, etc.

```css
    ul, li {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      list-style: none;
      gap: 1rem;
    }
```

Comment: I found my issue. It appears that ```display: inline-block;``` in one of my classes was making the the last 'star' appear lower than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```